# ARToolkit - ARSimple displays image instead of a cube

Tags: android, opengl-es, artoolkit

I'd like to make an application with augmented reality for android (like a "ARToolkit - ARSimple")

But I want to show an image on my marker instead of that in build cube.

ARSimple code:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Apply the ARToolKit projection matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix(), 0);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);        
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // If the marker is visible, apply its transformation, and draw a cube
    if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(markerID)) {
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(markerID), 0);
        cube.draw(gl);
    }
}
```

Do I need to create a textured quad object in OpenGL and use the image for the texture to do that?

What is the best example to follow?

Answer (score 1):

I found this example: http://android-coffee.com/tutorial-how-to-draw-3d-photo-cube-in-android-studio-1-4/ and made this https://github.com/Renannr/FotoCubo